# Command for sharing same folder with multiple names

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I’m currently working on an improvement of our deployment process and I’d really like to automate one of the new steps. Through Windows UI I can share the same folder on the network under multiple different names.
There is a prompt command for sharing (“NET SHARE _shared$=c:\Example”), but it only allows adding one shared name for the folder. Is there a prompt command for this and/or is there a way to do this programmatically, like with Windows API or even WMI?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I share the same folder with multiple names?

You can just run `net share` multiple times.

Example:

```
C:\test>net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark
C$           C:\                             Default share
F$           F:\                             Default share
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
The command completed successfully.


C:\test>net share aaa=f:\
aaa was shared successfully.

C:\test>net share bbb=f:\
bbb was shared successfully.

C:\test>net share

Share name   Resource                        Remark
ADMIN$       C:\Windows                      Remote Admin
IPC$                                         Remote IPC
C$           C:\                             Default share
F$           F:\                             Default share
aaa          f:\
bbb          f:\
The command completed successfully.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net share](http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html) - The NET Command is used to manage File Shares, Printer Shares and sessions.

Comment: NET SHARE _Release1.2=C:\Users\jjs\Desktop\test /grant:jjs,full
NET SHARE _Release1.2Beta=C:\Users\jjs\Desktop\test /grant:jjs,full
pause

Thanks a lot
:)