# Command for sharing same folder with multiple names

Tags: windows

I’m currently working on an improvement of our deployment process and I’d really like to automate one of the new steps. Through Windows UI I can share the same folder on the network under multiple different names.
There is a prompt command for sharing (“NET SHARE _shared$=c:\Example”), but it only allows adding one shared name for the folder. Is there a prompt command for this and/or is there a way to do this programmatically, like with Windows API or even WMI?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command for sharing same folder with multiple names](http://superuser.com/questions/946897/command-for-sharing-same-folder-with-multiple-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command prompt, you can use `mklink /D new-name existing-folder` to create a "directory symbolic link", then share the link.  For example:

```
net share documents=c:\users\michael\documents
mklink /d documents2 documents
net share documents2=c:\users\michael\documents2
```

This will create two shares, `documents` and `documents2` on `c:\users\michael\documents`.  The disadvantage is that you are going to have a `documents2` folder hanging around, which will be a symbolic link to the `documents` folder.

Friendly advice: if you decide to start playing with symbolic links, be sure to thoroughly read all the related documentation first.